# How to make PublisherAdView in circular shape

Tags: android, android-layout, double-click-advertising

Can any one please help me out .

I have implemented doubleClick add using PublisherAdView . But my requirement is to make adds in circular View.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create shape drawable and set backgrount for your android layout view.

android:shape="oval">

```
    <solid android:color="#9F2220"/>

    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#f23" />

    <size android:width="65dp" android:height="65dp"/>
```

Comment: follow this - you need to create shape drawable and set backgrount for your android layout view.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:shape="oval">

        <solid android:color="#9F2220"/>

        <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#f23" />

        <size android:width="65dp" android:height="65dp"/>

</shape>

Comment: No its not right because PublisherAddView will not change after setting the background drawable.